# List index out of list Python CSV files

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

so im learning some python but i got a list out of index error at this point if i put my header index to 0 it works not the way i see it works but ok, but if i get an upper index for header it wont can you help me out why?[photo of my csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDD13.png)

[heres the first picture of my code][and 2nd pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi0AC.png)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrhK8.png)

Comment: Send the code in the question description rather than as image because images cannot be copied or run.

Comment: Is the delimiter is `comma` or `tab`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put your header index as `0` what is output?

Assuming your delimiter is `tab`

```py
with open("sample.csv", "r") as csvfile:
   reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter='\t')
   headers = next(reader, None)
   print(headers[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

My delimeter was \t after i changed it to it problem all solved